# Form redirects to page /form_action_cc611e1d

Tags: drupal-8

I installed the contact_storage module so I can set a redirect path when completing a form, whenever I complete a form it apparently ignores whatever I have filled into the redirect path field and sends me to "/form_action_cc611e1d".

I have no idea where this comes from, the only reference I find to this path in my code is in the BigPipe core module, except this module has not been active in my project.

I've cleared cache a 100 times but to no avail. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Check your error or access error logs. It might have something to do with permissions

Comment: @VJamie Nothing comes up in the error logs, the access logs just mention a 404: POST /schade/form_action_cc611e1d HTTP/1.1" 404 44117
This happens both on my local windows machine and the linux dev server

Comment: I think the best option here is to use xDebug to see where it gets redirected. And (if you haven't done this already) if you have access to PHPStorm or some advanced IDE, try to search for every occurence of this form. Might pop something else than just BigPipe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the redirect only happens when attaching a js library in the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() of my form, this js adds some html (no form controls just some div's) and some click handlers.

This only happens in 1 of our 6 templates though so there must be something else interfering, unfortunately I ran out of time to further investigate this.

To fix the form I simply added the request uri to the form again:

```
 function schade_forms_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

    //attach JS
    $form['#attached'] = array(
      'library' => array(
        'insusite_forms/form',
      ),
    );

    //to prevent the form from redirecting to /form_action_cc611e1d after submit add the action link
    $form['#action'] = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  }
}
```